# Flatten Maybe structure in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I thought `join` of `Control.Monad` had the same capability of `Array.flat` in JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

However, it's against my expectation and the actual behavior is

```
f :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
f = \a -> join (Just a) -- works as I expected

f' :: a -> Maybe a
f' = \a -> join (Just a) -- I thought it returns Maybe a
-- Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Maybe a
-- Expected type: Maybe (Maybe a)     
-- Actual type:   Maybe a
```

Is there flatten function available instead or any workaround?

Comment: what would you expect, say, `f' 2` - that is `join (Just 2)` - to do?

Comment: `join` will convert a `Maybe (Maybe a)` to a `Maybe a`. You can not `join (Just a)` in the latter, since that has type `Maybe a`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I thought it to be `Just 2`, and I want to find way to do so, Thanks.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Right, that's what I understand now. I need to know another way the latter also works.

Comment: Why not just have `f' = Just`?  This seems like it could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Is there a larger problem that this is a part of that you are trying to solve? If so, we could probably help you more if you give details on the ultimate goal you are working towards with this.

Comment: To have something akin to javascript's `flat`, first you have to have a type that can represent different nesting depths, and `Maybe` ain't it. For example, think `data NestedMaybe a = Here a | Deeper (NestedMaybe (Maybe a))` or something, or the parameterized version, `data Nested f a = Here a | Deeper (Nested f (f a))`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks, the answer probably implemented that, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`join` flattens always exactly two layers down to one. Ideally we would like to express something like “recursively flatten any nested layers; if we're down to one layer, don't do anything”. This would require a type like

```
type family Flattened x where
  Flattened (m (m a)) = Flattened (m a)
  Flattened (m a) = m a

flatten :: x -> Flattened x
```

Actually, this can't (AFAIK) be implemented as such though, we need some heavy machinery:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, GADTs, ConstraintKinds
        , MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances
        , RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax
        , ScopedTypeVariables, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

import Control.Monad

type family Stripped m x where
  Stripped m (m a) = Stripped m a
  Stripped m x = x

type Bare m x = Stripped m x ~ x

data DepthSing m x where
  BareSing :: Bare m x => DepthSing m x
  DeepSing :: KnownDepth m x => DepthSing m (m x)

class KnownDepth m x where
  depth :: DepthSing m x

flatten :: ∀ m x . (Monad m, KnownDepth m x) => m x -> m (Stripped m x)
flatten p = case depth @m @x of
   BareSing -> p
   DeepSing -> flatten $ join p

instance KnownDepth m Char where
  depth = BareSing

instance KnownDepth m a => KnownDepth m (m a) where
  depth = DeepSing
```

Now

```
*Main> flatten (Just (Just 'v'))
Just 'v'
*Main> flatten (Just (Just (Just 'w')))
Just 'w'
*Main> flatten (Just 'i')
Just 'i'
```

Awkward is that we need a dedicated `KnownDepth` instance for every “primitive” type.

```
instance KnownDepth m Int where depth = BareSing
instance KnownDepth m Bool where depth = BareSing
...
```

Perhaps `-XIncoherentInstances` could help, but that's an extension I'm not touching.

A worse problem is that this doesn't work for flattening e.g. `Maybe (Maybe [Int])` to `Maybe [Int]`, we need *quadratically many* instances:

```
instance KnownDepth Maybe [x] where depth = BareSing
instance KnownDepth Maybe (Either c x) where depth = BareSing
...
instance KnownDepth [] (Maybe x) where depth = BareSing
instance KnownDepth [] (Either c x) where depth = BareSing
...
instance KnownDepth (Either c) [x] where depth = BareSing
instance KnownDepth (Either c) (Maybe x) where depth = BareSing
...
...
```

---

If you also want the behaviour `'w' -> Just 'w'`, this can be accomplished by

```
flatten' :: ∀ m x . (Monad m, KnownDepth m x) => x -> m (Stripped m x)
flatten' p = case depth @m @x of
   BareSing -> return p
   DeepSing -> flatten p
```

Comment: @eftaroundabout Wow! This is a great answer and actually library level. Very intricate code to study more than I have asked. Thanks a Lot!!!!!

Comment: @Functor you're welcome, but actually it's visible that this solution isn't really very useful, due to the big number of instances need. (Otherwise `flatten` would probably be widely used.)

Comment: Actually, could you  please give me the simplified version of the `depth` is only 1? I don't need the deep flatten and flattening only 1 level is always required. Of course only if this "fixed 1 level flatten" can simplify your code.

Comment: Nah, limiting the depth to 2 doesn't really change the main problem: you still need to find out whether or not the `x` in `Maybe x` is of the form `Maybe y`. The recursion is then the easy part.

Comment: Ok, thanks, One more last thing please. Using your technique, generally speaking in Haskell type system, is it possible to define a non-nesting Maybe monad that has idempotency, `unit a == Maybe a` and `unit (Maybe a) == Maybe a`. If possible, probably I will start new Q.

Comment: In other words, if it's not the Monad, wrap the naked value into the Monad, if it's already the Monad, return as it is.

Comment: `flatten'` already does that (as I wrote in response to chepner's comment).

Comment: @chepner Actually I had misunderstood your comment, Sorry about that. Thank you.